# Gitlab pushing first project failed due to could not read from remote repository

Tags: gitlab

I was new to Gitlab was trying to push my project from local machine to Gitlab.

Have done the SSH key and followed the instructions at Gitlab. Done the Git global setup. Was trying to add an existing folder , so i followed the instructions listed

```
cd existing_folder
git init
git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/sss/testnode.git
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git push -u origin master
```

but failed at the last step at the git push. The error message was 
[image]

Tried adding the remote origin, but it was told it already exists. So not sure where it went wrong. Please help, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

> Have done the SSH key

The problem is that you have defined your origin as HTTPS, not SSH.

Try:

```
git remote set-url origin git@gitlab.com:sss/testnode.git
```

That will override origin URL.

Independently, make sure your SSH key does work and allows GitLab to authenticate you as your GitLab account with:

```
ssh -T git@gitlab.com
```

Comment: what if i ssh -T git@gitlab.com, the reply was 'ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer'

Comment: That is your issue then: as long as that command does not work, any SSH URL for GitLab won't work. Is SSH blocked from where you are working?

Answer (score 0):

Check out your credentials, if they are invalid, it wont give u to upload changes.

For **Windows** check this: https://www.digitalcitizen.life/credential-manager-where-windows-stores-passwords-other-login-details

For **Linux** check this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/30907/password-management-applications (if you do not know how to change credentials via terminal)